# Delete a file when I pressed the button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to delete the file when I pressed the button.
My code is below

```
<html>
  <input type="button" value="Delete" onClick="if(confirm('Are you sure want to delete     Msg<?php $file="0000"; echo $file; ?>?'))
  <?php unlink("msg".$file.".wav");
        unlink("msg".$file.".gsm");
        unlink("msg".$file.".WAV");
        unlink("msg".$file.".txt");
  ?>
    alert('The Msg<?php echo $file; ?> is Deleted') 
else alert('The Msg<?php echo $file; ?> not Deleted')">
</html>
```

But it not works

Comment: Its better to give a function name in onclick and then writing what all actions you need to perform in that function.

Comment: PHP runs on the server.  Javscript runs on the client's machine.  You can't execute PHP on the client's machine, which means that Javascript (running on the client's machine), can't run PHP code (because PHP runs only on the server).  Instead, you can make a call to a PHP script by submitting a form or sending it using AJAX.  That PHP script can remove the file and report back to the user.

Comment: How this will work. where is your function? where is your deletion code.

Comment: you need to get a book / video tutorial to get understand server script and client script.. your code will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few problems here.

Firstly, you don't ever finish your `onClick` attribute, so this is likely to result in JavaScript errors. Check this in your console. If you are using `onClick` it is best to keep JavaScript brief in here — write a JavaScript function, and call it from this event.

Any PHP you have will be run when the page is served. Thus, your deletions will be done immediately, and not inside the JavaScript `if` statement as you want. You can achieve this in one of two ways:

- Set up a post method form to do a trip to the server, in which you do your file deletions
- Use an AJAX call to do a similar thing in the background. Libraries like jQuery will make this easy for you

Lastly, it is unclear how you would want the `$file` to be populated. If this depend on the button you press on, you'll need to read that in either of the above approaches, and then detect the name on the server side.

As others have said, there is no substitute for sitting down for a good bit of study with a book or a video. It's frustrating when you just want to make something, but you'll find it a good time investment in the long term. Stick at it!

Answer (score 2):

I think this question shows that there's a lack of understanding on how server side and client side code works. To achieve this sort of thing, you will need to send a request to your server, perform the action and then return some output to the user - short of re-writing your code for you, there's not a lot we can do on here.

The documentation for `unlink()` is available on the PHP website: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

If you search the web, there are plenty of tutorials showing you how to achieve this sort of thing. Here's an example though: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filedelete.php